# Encoding a Ecto Model to JSON in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am going over the following tutorial in an attempt to get my head around elixir and phoenix:

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/testing-a-phoenix-elixir-json-api

I am running into an issue with the test, mainly using Poison.encode! on the Contact model. I get the following error:

```
unable to encode value: {nil, "contacts"}
```

This led me to the following issue:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/840
and the fix:
https://coderwall.com/p/fhsehq/fix-encoding-issue-with-ecto-and-poison

I have added the code from the blog article into lib/poison_encoder.ex, but I now get the following error:

```
no function clause matching in Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
```

The code I have in lib/poison_encoder.ex:

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Any do
  def encode(%{__struct__: _} = struct, options) do
    map = struct
          |> Map.from_struct
          |> sanitize_map
    Poison.Encoder.Map.encode(map, options)
  end

  defp sanitize_map(map) do
    Map.drop(map, [:__meta__, :__struct__])
  end
end
```

Comment: Please include the code you have in your `lib/poison_encoder.ex` in the post

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Update to Poison 1.5. With it you can declare in your models:

```
@derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:foo, :bar, :baz]}
schema "your schema" do
  field :foo
  field :bar
  field :baz
end
```

It is going to be faster, safer and cleaner.

Comment: Can you please describe "it didn't work"? There are many reasons why it could happen so without a proper description, it is really hard to figure out what else should be done.

Comment: I'd love to see more examples, demonstrating this. https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L53 > `@derive` - the same as `@derive` available in `Kernel.defstruct/1` as the schema defines a struct behind the scenes;

Comment: Note that this can be done with Jason as well   ```@derive {Jason.Encoder, only: [:name, :other_field]}```

Comment: Is there a way to make it `camelCase` on encoding instead of `snake_case`?