# returning a list gives (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

IO.puts(inspect( contacts )) gives:

```
 [%HelloTable.Contact{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, 
 id: 37,   
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-10-22T12:50:43Z>, 
 name: "Gumbo", phone: "(801) 555-55555", 
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-10-22T12:50:43Z>}]
```

And the view looks like:

```
defmodule HelloTable.ContactView do
  use HelloTable.Web, :view

  def render("index.json", %{contacts: contacts}) do
    IO.puts(inspect( contacts ))
    contacts
  end

end
```

As soon as I try to render this view I get:

```
** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {nil, "contacts"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to either implement the `Poison.Encoder` protocol for `HelloTable.Contact` as described in [Encoding a Ecto Model to JSON in elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549712/encoding-a-ecto-model-to-json-in-elixr/32553676#32553676) or return a map from the render function using [render_many/4](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_many/4):

```
defmodule HelloTable.ContactView do
  use HelloTable.Web, :view

  def render("index.json", %{contacts: contacts}) do
    render_many(contacts, __MODULE__, "contact.json")
  end

  def render("contact.json", %{contact: contact}) do
    %{
      id: contact.id,
      name: contact.name,
      phone_number: contact.phone
    }
  end    
end
```

The above is how JSON is handled with in the [Phoenix JSON generators](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/d59bebd61fdfff175f5621c38979a050046a5dd1/priv/templates/phoenix.gen.json/view.ex).

Comment: thanks, it works, just missing comma after contact.name.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Also you are missing `%{data: render_many...}%` in your first `def`.

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly cleaner solution using later versions of poison is described in [this response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549712/encoding-a-ecto-model-to-json-in-elixir/32553676#32553676).

Add this line of code to your model:

```
@derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :phone]}
```

(you can also include :updated_at if you want that field included in your JSON)