# Duplicated modules in phoenix mix release

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

I'm trying to run the `mix release` task to create a production phoenix server.

I was having an issue with poison so added the workaround from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/fhsehq/fix-encoding-issue-with-ecto-and-poison). However now when I run the release task I get the following error:

```
Errors generating release 
      Duplicated modules: 
    'Elixir.Poison.Encoder.Any' specified in poison and myappname
```

I tried adding the following line in `lib/myappname.ex` based on instructions from [elixir getting started](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html). But it didn't have any effect.

```
defmodule Myappname do
  use Application

  @derive [Poison.Encoder]
  # ...
```

Comment: That post doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That workaround should be avoided in most recent releases of poison. If serving json you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549712/encoding-a-ecto-model-to-json-in-elixir/32553676#32553676).